# how to display just one or a few chosen column values when read a csv file in javafx

Tags: java, csv, user-interface, javafx

I am writing a personal program that can read in a CSV file, then take that information and display in a user-friendlier format.

So my question is how can I just display, let say, the 4th, 5th, 6th column and 10th value of that row in the CSV table format in JavaFX.

For example, my CSV table is something like this:

[image: example]

and I want it to display something like

monostamp: [values]

lat: [value]

and the value is corresponding to each other row.

I have the code that read in the csv and display all of the row and column in Tableview but not too sure how to pick out a specific column and row to display.

```
 package sample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.lang.String;

public class readCSV extends Application {

    public class Record {
        //Assume each record have 6 elements, all String

        private SimpleStringProperty f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12;

        public String getF1() {
            return f1.get();
        }

        public String getF2() {
            return f2.get();
        }

        public String getF3() {
            return f3.get();
        }

        public String getF4() {
            return f4.get();
        }

        public String getF5() {
            return f5.get();
        }

        public String getF6() {
            return f6.get();
        }

        public String getF7() {
            return f7.get();
        }

        public String getF8() {
            return f8.get();
        }

        public String getF9() {
            return f9.get();
        }

        public String getF10() {
            return f10.get();
        }

        public String getF11() {
            return f11.get();
        }

        public String getF12() {
            return f12.get();
        }

        Record(String f1, String f2, String f3, String f4,
               String f5, String f6,String f7, String f8, String f9, String f10,
               String f11, String f12) {
            this.f1 = new SimpleStringProperty(f1);
            this.f2 = new SimpleStringProperty(f2);
            this.f3 = new SimpleStringProperty(f3);
            this.f4 = new SimpleStringProperty(f4);
            this.f5 = new SimpleStringProperty(f5);
            this.f6 = new SimpleStringProperty(f6);
            this.f7 = new SimpleStringProperty(f7);
            this.f8 = new SimpleStringProperty(f8);
            this.f9 = new SimpleStringProperty(f9);
            this.f10 = new SimpleStringProperty(f10);
            this.f11 = new SimpleStringProperty(f11);
            this.f12 = new SimpleStringProperty(f12);
        }

    }

    private final TableView<Record> tableView = new TableView<>();

    private final ObservableList<Record> dataList
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("flight logs panel");

        Group root = new Group();

        TableColumn columnF1 = new TableColumn("f1");
        columnF1.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f1"));

        TableColumn columnF2 = new TableColumn("f2");
        columnF2.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f2"));

        TableColumn columnF3 = new TableColumn("f3");
        columnF3.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f3"));

        TableColumn columnF4 = new TableColumn("f4");
        columnF4.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f4"));

        TableColumn columnF5 = new TableColumn("f5");
        columnF5.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f5"));

        TableColumn columnF6 = new TableColumn("f6");
        columnF6.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f6"));


        TableColumn columnF7 = new TableColumn("f7");
        columnF7.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f7"));

        TableColumn columnF8 = new TableColumn("f8");
        columnF8.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f8"));

        TableColumn columnF9 = new TableColumn("f9");
        columnF9.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f9"));

        TableColumn columnF10 = new TableColumn("f10");
        columnF10.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f10"));

        TableColumn columnF11 = new TableColumn("f11");
        columnF11.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f11"));

        TableColumn columnF12 = new TableColumn("f12");
        columnF12.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("f12"));


        tableView.setItems(dataList);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(
                columnF1, columnF2, columnF3, columnF4, columnF5, columnF6,
                columnF7, columnF8, columnF9, columnF10, columnF11, columnF12);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setSpacing(100);
        vBox.getChildren().add(tableView);

        root.getChildren().add(vBox);


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 500));
        //primaryStage.show();

        readCSV();
    }

    private void readCSV() {

        String CsvFile = "C:\\Users\\Jack Vu\\IdeaProjects\\Flight_panel/flight_log.csv";
        String FieldDelimiter = ",";

        BufferedReader br;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CsvFile));

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] fields = line.split(FieldDelimiter, -1);

                Record record = new Record(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2],
                        fields[3], fields[4], fields[5],fields[6], fields[7], fields[8],
                        fields[9], fields[10], fields[11]);
                dataList.add(record);

            }

        }

//        try {
//            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CsvFile));
//
//            String line;
//            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
//                if (line == "monoStamp"){
//                   System.out.print("here");
//                }
//
//            }
//
//        }
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(readCSV.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(readCSV.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

//
//    private void displayColumn(){
//        String CsvFile = "C:\\Users\\Jack Vu\\IdeaProjects\\Flight_panel/flight_log.csv";
//        String FieldDelimiter = ",";
//
//        BufferedReader br;
//        
//
//
//    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

EDIT:
for final version of the program, I want the value of monostamp to be auto increment and if that increment match the value of monostamp, it will show the monostamp value and the lat value in the same row.

something like:

monostamp:  1470483977 (this is row 1)

lat:       39.1245

and 0.5 sec later (or shorter time perios)

monostamp: 147048376 (this is row 6th)

lat: 39.1245

Comment: See that `tableView.getColumns().addAll(…)` line?  You don’t have to add all of those columns.  Just add the ones you want to be shown in the window.

Comment: yeah. I have been playing around with that. The addAll was there as debugging tool because i want to see if it actually import all the value. My bad.Should have left that one out. However, it will  show them in column (like 300 lines of them) and not very different from open CSV file in excel. I want it to be line by line by line because later on, I would like to implement some auto increment (like time laps) to go through them all and show each row correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

Just use [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to read your CSV, with only the columns you are targeting:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.selectFields("Field A", "Field X", "Field Z");
//also parserSettings.selectIndexes(4, 0, 1);
List<String[]> parsedRows = new CsvParser(parserSettings).parseAll(new File(csvFile));
```

This will return rows with the data of your selected columns, in the order you defined. Hope it helps!

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache v2.0 license)